# chat among windows server remote users

Tags: chat, windows-server

I wonder is there any software makes the chat among windows server remote users available? especially windows server 2012 R2. I know there are many software for the chat under a local network, but do not know whether they can be used under the same ip but different users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use IPMsg.  It's free.  It handles attachments as well.

Comment: does it support multi-user under same ip?

Comment: Its more like a messaging system.  You can send one or more users (from a picklist) a message including attachment.  It is multi-user but not interactive chat